# Neo4j: how to compare two nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a following query. The goal of the query is to get all the nodes except certain nodes

```
MATCH (u:User) 
WHERE NOT exists(u.canceled)
WITH u
MATCH (u1:User)
WHERE NOT exist(u.password) AND NOT u
RETURN u1
```

I got **Type mismatch: expected Boolean but was Node** Error.

How can i get all 'u1' nodes without 'u' nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is for this line :

```
WHERE NOT exist(u.password) AND NOT u
```

especially the `AND NOT u`

If you want to say that u1 should not be the same node as u, then you should write the following :

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS(u.password)
AND u1 <> u
```